# Match function returns error: Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to modify code that adds days to holidays, when searching in defined holidays array match function returns mismatch type 13 error.

```
Public Function Add2DaysAndSkipHolidayList(ByVal dateInputOutput As Date) As Date    
    Dim index As Long

    dateInputOutput = dateInputOutput

    If Weekday(dateInputOutput, vbMonday) = 7 Then
        dateInputOutput = dateInputOutput + 1
    ElseIf Weekday(dateInputOutput, vbMonday) = 6 Then
        dateInputOutput = dateInputOutput + 2
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    Do
        index = 0
        index = Application.Match(dateInputOutput, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Holiday").Range("A:A").Value, 0)
        dateInputOutput = dateInputOutput + 1
    Loop While Not index = 0

    On Error GoTo 0

    dateInputOutput = dateInputOutput - 1

    If Weekday(dateInputOutput, vbMonday) = 7 Then
        dateInputOutput = dateInputOutput + 1
    ElseIf Weekday(dateInputOutput, vbMonday) = 6 Then
        dateInputOutput = dateInputOutput + 2
    End If

    Add2DaysAndSkipHolidayList = dateInputOutput
End Function
```

It works fine while checking Saturday, and Sundays, when checking predefined holidays, match returns type mismatch error. I'm working with Office 365

Comment: In which line do you get the error? Since you use `On Error Resume Next` your `Match` function can't throw an exception.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Peh I did some debbuging and identified this line: index = Application.Match(dateInputOutput, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Holiday").Range("A:A").Value, 0)

Comment: @Scottt Cranner I want to identify holiday and add days so it's next working day. I wan't to check on holidays, like easter and such. Plus in some cases skip workdays like monday

Comment: There is already a formula that does that [WORKDAY.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workday-intl-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d)

Comment: I have acctivities were i need to skip more than just weekends, but two additional days